# Using modified 'meta_key' to set 'orderby' in WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query

Let's say I have a query like this:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(
                array(
                    'post_type' => 'special',
                    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                    'meta_key' => 'my_orderby_field',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                    ));
```

Say I needed to remove three first characters from the content of "my_orderby_field' before using it to order the fields. I don't want to change the actual value itself because those characters make sense when the value's shown client-side, but here, they mix up the ordering.

Is there a way to use for example php string operators right there in the query just for the sake of ordering the results?

Comment: For the sake of example, imagine the 'my_orderby_field' values contained strings like 'zzzapple', 'yyybanana' and 'xxxcarrot'.

Comment: to do this, it's better to make 2 fields, one with "zzz" and one with "apple". then you can make the sort and client side you show concatenation of the 2 fields

Comment: Thanks mmm! I agree, but if you weren't allowed to add any fields for one reason or another, is it possible to solve this along the lines of my original question?

Comment: Why not test it and answer your own question?